# ways to connect Lotus notes client?

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I'm just curious to know the way of connecting Lotus notes, i have seen people using

1) Lotus notes installed in the machine

2) Lotus notes using citrix

Can anyone tell me is there any other possibility to connect lotus notes?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by connecting? Your example suggests "Installing". You also have Notes in the browser for ND9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more:

- IBM Notes running on Windows Terminal Services
- IBM Notes on smartphones and tablets via IBM Notes Traveler  (mail, calendar and contacts)
- IBM Notes in the browser using IBM iNotes (mail, calendar and contacts)
- IBM Notes running as a full client in the browser using the IBM Notes Browser Plugin

Comment: Thank a lot Pen Henrik, Checking release 9  Browser Plugin.